# Spring Data MongoDB - Long values are coming null in response using Repository query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am developing `Spring Boot MongoDB` example using `V2.4.5`. In this example when I am doing repository query, Long fields values are not getting mapped. Sample document value from MongoDB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a536412306ab5bdd7a6b06"),
    "user" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "firstname" : "vins",
        "lastname" : "guru",
        "email" : "admin@vinsguru.com"
    },
    "product" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "description" : "ipad"
    },
    "price" : 300
}
```

OrderController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order-service")
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private PurchaseOrderService purchaseOrderService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<PurchaseOrder> getAllOrders() {
        return this.purchaseOrderService.getPurchaseOrders();
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public void createOrder(@RequestBody PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) {
        this.purchaseOrderService.createPurchaseOrder(purchaseOrder);
    }
}
```

PurchaseOrderServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PurchaseOrderServiceImpl implements PurchaseOrderService {

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseOrderRepository purchaseOrderRepository;

    @Override
    public List<PurchaseOrder> getPurchaseOrders() {
        return this.purchaseOrderRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void createPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) {
        this.purchaseOrderRepository.save(purchaseOrder);
    }

}
```

PurchaseOrder.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "purchase_order")
public class PurchaseOrder {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private User user;
    private Product product;
    private double price;
}
```

User.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
}
```

Product.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String description;
}
```

Output I am getting is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a536412306ab5bdd7a6b06"),
    "user" : {
        "id" : null,
        "firstname" : "vins",
        "lastname" : "guru",
        "email" : "admin@vinsguru.com"
    },
    "product" : {
        "id" : null,
        "description" : "ipad"
    },
    "price" : 300
}
```

PurchaseRepository.java

```
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends MongoRepository<PurchaseOrder, String> {
    @Query("{ 'user.id': ?0 }")
    List<PurchaseOrder> findByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

[image]

Comment: just curious, have you tried with integers? Or can u tell me what is the data type that saved in db?

Comment: double check your database, the id is ObjectId or Long? (int32/ int64). This measn, you try to convert ObjectId to Long

Comment: And pls post the repository too

Comment: I noticed some problems, you defined Long as id in purchesedOrder. But it was saved as ObjectId in db. So better you can make it as `private ObjectId _id;`, elese you can write custom converters or you can even you setters to set values to id. If you gonna use ObjectId, then change string to  `MongoRepository<PurchaseOrder, ObjectId>`. You don't need even `@Query`, you can use, `findByUser_id(Long id)` . Underscore (_) used for go inside the objects. And its readable

Comment: Since you are using spring boot and its handling dependancy injection, `PurchaseOrderService` interface is redundant, you may remove it, you can inject the service class in controller directly.

Comment: Thanks I followed your all suggestions and still giving below response 

`[{"_id":{"timestamp":1621443301,"date":1621443301000},"user":{"id":null,"firstname":"vins","lastname":"guru","email":"admin@vinsguru.com"},"product":{"id":0,"description":"ipad"},"price":300.0}]` - id values are still null

Comment: I will also have a look

Comment: Source Code publish here  - https://github.com/javaHelper/saga.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get null, Mongodb default field of id is `_id`. And spring data converts id to `_id` in any classes. When you try to run, you can check the console `find using query: { "user._id" : 1} fields: Document{{}}`. It mentioned `_id` there also which is not mapped to database, database has `id`. (No underscore). To over come this problem ,you can use `@Field`.

```
public class User {
    @Field("id")
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
}
```

Or you can use `_id` everywhere(In classes and collections)

Comment: Thanks for detailed response, still code is not working well, could you please try ? I have posted all code

Comment: I have tried wht you gave and checked (not git). I will check git code also. Give me some time

Comment: I haven't installed gradle, im using maven, with your code, its working fine for me. Postman img https://ibb.co/60tSPr7 . Check you have added `@Field("id")` in user

Comment: Noticed in the git `@Query("{ 'user.userId': ?0 }")` should be `@Query("{ 'user.id': ?0 }")`

Comment: I  just modified in another project, need to create, maven ok?

Comment: Thanks, its working now only getting `"_id": {
            "timestamp": 1621440065,
            "date": 1621440065000
        },` for _id field

Comment: Thats awesome! Yu can carry on

Comment: For that ObjectId problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710033/5669842 this will help you