# Is there a way to make spring boot mongodb not changing your id attribute value to his object_id?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I am working in a project to learn spring boot, i have a problem where i have a attribute actor_id stored in mongodb with a value x but when i do mongoRepository.findall(), he changes the value of my actor_id to the value of the object_id generated automatically by mongodb, so even if i want to find a value by id i have to put the object_id value instead of the value of actor_id stored in database. Image below to better help understand.
[image]
I wanted that the returned value of a get http://localhost:8093/actors in actor_id be = 1 instead of 61634ad37e775d4b87635129.

Below is my code.
Actor.java:

```
package com.film.SpringAplication.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoId;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;


@Document(collection="actor")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Actor {
    @Id
    String actor_id;
    String first_name;
    String last_name;       
}
```

ActorController.java

```
package com.film.SpringAplication.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.film.SpringAplication.model.Actor;
import com.film.SpringAplication.service.ActorService;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/actors")
public class ActorController {
    @Autowired
    ActorService actorService;


    @PostMapping
    public String addActor(@RequestBody Actor actor) {
        return actorService.addActor(actor);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Actor> getActors() {    
        return actorService.getActors();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public List<Actor> getActor(@PathVariable String id) {
        return actorService.getActor(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String deleteActor(@PathVariable String id) {
        return actorService.deleteActor(id);
    }
}
```

ActorService.java:

```
package com.film.SpringAplication.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.film.SpringAplication.model.Actor;
import com.film.SpringAplication.repository.ActorRepository;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ActorService {
    private final ActorRepository actorRepository;
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    public String addActor(Actor actor) {
        actorRepository.save(actor);
        return "Actor Added";
    }
    public List<Actor> getActors() {
        List<Actor> lista = actorRepository.findAll();
        return lista;
    }
    public List<Actor> getActor(String id) {
        Query query=new Query()
                .addCriteria(Criteria.where("actor_id").is(id));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query,Actor.class);
        //return actorRepository.findById(id);
    }
    public String deleteActor(String id) {
        actorRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "User deleted";
    }
}
```

ActorRepository.java:

```
package com.film.SpringAplication.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.film.SpringAplication.model.Actor;

public interface ActorRepository extends MongoRepository<Actor,String>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can use `@Field`. You annotate `@Id` to `actor_id`. So basically it takes as the default primary key. You can do two things. You can annotate `_id` as default primary key.

```
@Document(collection="actor")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Actor {
    @Id
    ObjectId _id;   
    String actor_id;
    String first_name;
    String last_name;       
}
```

Else you can annotate `@Field`

```
@Document(collection="actor")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Actor {
    @Id
    @Field("actor_id")
    String actor_id;
    String first_name;
    String last_name;       
}
```

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608342/7975771)

Comment: First of all thank you. The @Field for some reason didn't work and the objectId one kinda worked, because now in the output the actor_id didn't changed but when i do a query ` Query query=new Query()
    .addCriteria(Criteria.where("actor_id").is(id));` the output is empty even tho the id exists in the database and if i do the same query but with the Criteria.(first_name).is(name) the ouput is correct. Somehow i still can't use the actor_id field.